# Problem with can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord, webhooks

when i want to send discord message with text from span i get this
'''can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str'''
Prints works but send discord webhook not.

So this is my question how to fix that.

my code:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import bs4
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webhook=DiscordWebhook(url="X")
link='https://.com'

def sizes():
   r=requests.get(link)
   soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
   Size=soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'js-tooltipContent g-dn'})
   for span in Size:
       print(span.text.replace('EU:','').strip())

embed = DiscordEmbed(
    title= "size", 
    description= "sizes: " + sizes(),
    color=242424,
    )
    
webhook.add_embed(embed)
response = webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Yes,  I want to return that

Comment: Have you tried to covert it explicitly to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `sizes` doesn't return anything. `print` does not return values, it just prints. You'd need to do something like:

```
acc = ""
for span in Size:
   acc += span.text.replace('EU:','').strip()  # Concatenate the strings together
return acc
```

There are also more efficient ways of doing this using a list comprehension/generator expression and `join`:

```
return "".join(span.text.replace('EU:','').strip() for span in Size)
```

But that's getting a little more complicated.

Comment: It don't works perfectly because, only first line of text is returning not all.

Comment: There is size: S,M,L,XL,XXL  , but script is returning only S

Comment: @DemonsAreHere4000 This will concatenate all the `span`s together. If you're not getting the rest of the sizes, that suggests that `Size` is missing the data. Do `print(Size)` before the loop to verify the data.

Comment: print(Size) is printing all sizes

Comment: `soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'js-tooltipContent g-dn'})

Out[144]: 
[<span class="js-tooltipContent g-dn">
          EU: S
         </span>,
 <span class="js-tooltipContent g-dn">
          EU: M
         </span>,
 <span class="js-tooltipContent g-dn">
          EU: L
         </span>,
 <span class="js-tooltipContent g-dn">
          EU: XL
         </span>,
 <span class="js-tooltipContent g-dn">
          EU: XXL
         </span>]`

Comment: @DemonsAreHere4000 What does `print(sizes())` give? It could be how the `description=` is using the string.

Comment: @DemonsAreHere4000 No problem. I updated my answer with a second way as well.